# Error handling: returning build-in error vs custom type

Tags: go, error-handling

In Go's standard libraries, the built-in `error` is used for error handling. [This post](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) used some examples from the std libs to demonstrate how error handling works in Go.

```
package net

type Error interface {
    error
    Timeout() bool   // Is the error a timeout?
    Temporary() bool // Is the error temporary?
}

if nerr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nerr.Temporary() {
    time.Sleep(1e9)
    continue
}
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I am wondering what would be the benefits of sticking to this convention.
What if we return the custom type? e.g. `net.Error` type.

Comment: The fact that it's a convention is benefit enough, at least in my book.

Comment: [The lanugage is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Comment: @mkopriva it should be the opposite. It has benefits and becomes a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the difference between `DoRequest() error` vs `DoRequest() net.SomeSpecificError`.

Following code

```
type CustomError struct {
}

func (CustomError) Error() string {
    return "custom error"
}

func DoRequest() *CustomError {
    return nil
}

func MarkTaskComplete() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := DoRequest()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = MarkTaskComplete()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

will fail to compile because error returned by `MarkTaskComplete` cannot be assigned to err variable which is of type `*SomeError`.

Second disadvantage is that you cannot return from `DoRequest` any other error than `SomeError`. There may be a few situations where you would benefit from such a restriction, but in general in most cases the approach with `error` is more flexible. Especially when your function calls another one.

It is also worth to read [about the errors wrapping](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors)

Answer (score -1):

The benefits of the customer type, ie net.Error is:

```
    type Error interface {

    error
    Timeout() bool   // Is the error a timeout?
    Temporary() bool // Is the error temporary?
}
```

The above has the advantage of being more descriptive. We get more information about the error like whether it is a Timeout error or a Temporary error.

In addition to that, we also get to know the primary data which is in the primary field "error", in the above example, which is a string.

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```